# Post-optimality analysis: Change in one of the constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the LP:

> \begin{array}{rccc}
> \max& \quad
> -3x_1&-x_2& & \\
> \text{s.t.}& \quad
> 2x_1&+x_2 &\leq 3 \\
> & -x_1&+x_2 &\geq 1 \\
> &&x_1,x_2 &\geq 0
> \end{array}

Suppose I have solved the above problem for the optimal solution. (I used dual simplex and get $(0,1)$ as the optimal solution.)
Now if the first constraint $(2x_1+x_2 \leq 3)$ is either changed to

> 1. $\max\{2x_1+x_2,0\} \leq 3$, or
> 2. $\max\{2x_1+x_2,6\} \leq 3$,

is it possible to obtain the new optimal solution without having to solve the entire problem from the scratch?

I have tried introducing a new variable $t$ to address the maximum and rewrite the constraints in linear form but it doesn't seem to help.

Any hint or comment is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The constraint (1) $\max\{2x_1+x_2,0\} \leq 3$ is redundant since it's satisfied by the current optimal solution.

Comment: The constraint (2) $\max\{2x_1+x_2,6\} \leq 3$ is *meaningless* because $\max\{2x_1+x_2,6\} \geq 6 > 3$, so the feasible region will become empty.